# how to disable autoscroll when bot replacing message in in slack interactive messsage?

Tags: slack-api

When a slack user send my bot a message, my bot will reply with buttons. the button will utilize slack interactive message.

When user click on one of that buttons, the bot will replace the message with several texts and attachments.

my problem is that interactive message trigger scroll down to the end. how can I keep slack app not scrolling down when bot replying a message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

You have very little control of how the Slack UI is rendering your message. And Slack will always render a new message at the bottom of a channel, which is why your updated message "scrolls down".

In general this is a feature, since Slack is made to be 100% platform agnostic and your apps will work just as well on e.g. browser, windows client or iPhone app.